# IID_MediaControl undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, c, directshow, linker-errors

I'm developping a SmartDevice Win32 DLL for my device with Windows Mobile 6.1 using Visual Studio 2008. I have to use DirectShow and I started reproducing the basic example.

The `.h`:

```
#pragma once

// Additional Include Directories:
// "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Smartphone\Include\Armv4i"
#include <dshow.h>

// Included strmiids.lib for CLSID_FilterGraph and IID_IGraphBuilder (.cpp)
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")



extern "C" {

    __declspec(dllexport) bool InitCOM();

}
```

And the `.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DLLDevice.h"


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}



__declspec(dllexport) bool InitCOM()
{
    if(FAILED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return false;

    IGraphBuilder* pGraphBuilder = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**) &pGraphBuilder);

    if(FAILED(hr))
        return false;

    IMediaControl *pMediaControl = NULL;
    hr = pGraphBuilder->QueryInterface(IID_MediaControl, (void**) &pMediaControl);


    pGraphBuilder->Release();

    return true;
}
```

Now I have a linker error:

```
error C2065: 'IID_MediaControl' : undeclared identifier
```

Why? How can I solve this problem?
**Why is thus impossible to create a project with DirectShow?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is `IID_IMediaControl`, not `IID_MediaControl`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading programming microsoft directShow for digital video and television and in COM Basic he wrote IID_MediaControl, I don't know why...

Comment: The interface is `IMediaControl`, `IID_` is typical prefix for associated IID. With most of the interfaces you can also use `__uuidof(IMediaControl)` instead.